# How to prevent or handle user input while ajax call is out and new data will be returned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My Angular app has a save call which saves data to the database and returns the saved data back to the model, so that the model gets repopulated with the latest data after the save. The issue that I currently face is that while the save is happening, the model can change.
For example, if the save call takes 2 seconds to be completed and then loads the data back, within that 2 second time gap, users will continue to type their form data to the form that is bound to the model. 
When the model from the server gets reloaded, the form will loose the data typed in between the save initiation point and completion point.

Any good suggestions to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to hide/disable the input while the call is out (that should be very brief). You could simply use a flag variable like `ng-disabled="callIsOut"` or `ng-hide="callIsOut"`.

If you really need them to be able to enter data in the meantime, there's no reason you couldn't compare the current user input with the freshly received data and replace the user data in the received data object.

Here's some sample code: **[Live demo (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/MBtSU3gFUdipoJtnMg4c?p=preview)**

```
<h1>Update</h1>
<input type="text" ng-model="otherInput">
<span ng-show="callIsOut">Saving...</span>
<button ng-click="otherSave()">Save</button>

<hr>

<h1>Disable</h1>
<input type="text" ng-model="myInput" ng-disabled="callIsOut">
<span ng-show="callIsOut">Saving...</span>
<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>

<hr>

<h1>Hide</h1>
<input type="text" ng-model="myInput" ng-hide="callIsOut">
<span ng-show="callIsOut">Saving...</span>
<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.callIsOut = false;

  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.callIsOut = true;
    myService.save($scope.myInput).then(function(data) {
      $scope.myInput = data;
      $scope.callIsOut = false;
    });
    $scope.myInput = '';
  };

  $scope.otherSave = function() {
    $scope.callIsOut = true;
    myService.save($scope.otherInput).then(function(data) {
      if ($scope.otherInput === '') {
        $scope.otherInput = data;
      }
      $scope.callIsOut = false;
    });
    $scope.otherInput = '';
  };
});
```